# Chilkat CkUpload Class fails to add Authorization header

Tags: c++, chilkat

The class **CkUpload** fails to add the **Authorization** header, using the AddCustomHeader method. You can add other custom headers but not the **Authorization** header.

For example,

```
CkUpload upload;
upload.AddCustomHeader("Authorization", "Bearer <token>");
```

You can verify it with the method **UploadToMemory**, which prints the whole request, lacking said header.

I'm using Chilkat version 9.5.0.95, C++, on Windows, with MS Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in v9.5.0.96, to be released at the end of this month.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you!